# Python Parser for programming beginner (german umlaute needed)

Tags: python, parsing, pyparsing

I was hoping someone could give me some feedback on the following package:

[Pyparsing](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/pyparsing/pyparsing.pdf)

I want to write a python program that takes, as input, a .txt file, and as output some kind of structured data in .csv or even excel format. A friend who quit the project tried something with ANTLR + Java, but german Umlaute "ä,ö,ü" made trouble. Now I (as a programming beginner) would like to write a program that works. I know some Matlab, but that's it. I started a coursera module on python programming (*Python for everyone*) to learn the basics.

**I now wanted to ask whether the mentioned "package" pyparsing can handle german umlaute or whether I will run into trouble here**.

In other words: If you were to recommend a python parsing strategy to a noob, what would it be?

Comment: You will need to use unicode, other than that, show what you are attempting. This question doesn't explain well what you are trying to do.

Comment: Yes, `pyparsing.alphas8bit` includes umlauts and the ß letter.

Comment: As one of the founders of this website famously noted, [There Ain't No Such Thing As Plain Text.](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) What encoding does the "`.txt`" input file use?

Comment: Also, as handling of Unicode strings is done a bit differently between Python 2 and Python 3, it might be useful to state what Python version(s) you intend to use.

Comment: There are many cases of pyparsing being used with character sets beyond 7-bit ASCII. pyparsing's 8bit builtin strings should be sufficient for parsing German, but you can custom create your own character sets using unicode strings also.

Answer (score 1):

On page 46 of your documentation is the section 7.15.printables: All the printable non-whitespace character. These are listed:

```
>>> len(pp.printables)
94
>>> print pp.printables
0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ!"#$%&'()*+,-
./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~
```

As you can see there are no german umlauts in there. This is because the project uses standard ASCII encoding instead of utf-8 which would support every character you could possibly want. This is most likely due to them using Python 2 instead of Python 3.

EDIT: I've just found the following on their website:

> NOTE - Pyparsing 2.x supports Python versions 2.6, 2.7, and 3.x. If you are using Python 2.5 or older, you must specifcally install version 1.5.7.
>      See more info on the News page

Theoratically you should be able to use utf-8 when you install the module for Python 3. Unfortunately the updated Documentation does not mention printables so I can't be sure.

Comment: Yes, `printables` is definitely 7-bit-oriented. However, pyparsing also provides character sets for 8-bit characters as well, `alphas8bit` and `punc8bit`, and larger user-defined character sets are supported as well.